# case statement for range of numbers

Tags: bash, case

I am writing a script.

```
case "${x_time}" in
  10) cp fileA fileB
      ;;
  20) cp fileC fileD
      ;;
  *) echo "Please check the $x_time"
      ;;
esac
```

I want `1..10` instead of `10` and `11..20` instead of `20`. e.g. `(1|2|3|...|10)` I mean, if `$x_time is 7`, the `first block` should execute and for `18, the second block` for `21, the *)`.

Any solution for checking the list of `$x_time`?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[[ ]]` tests instead:

```
if [[ $x_time -ge 1 && $x_time -le 10 ]]; then
    cp fileA fileB
elif [[ $x_time -ge 11 && $x_time -le 20 ]]; then
    cp fileC fileD
else
    echo "Please check the $x_time"
fi
```

It may also be possible to use `(( ))` at your preference.

```
if (( x_time >= 1 && x_time <= 10 )); then
    cp fileA fileB
elif (( x_time >= 11 && x_time <= 20 )); then
    cp fileC fileD
else
    echo "Please check the $x_time"
fi
```

Comment: I actually used the `if ... fi`, but I am looking for the similar multiple `OR` in case.
anyway, thanks.